# News system in PHP and Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have been trying to get this system to work for a few hours and still not able to get it to work. This is a direct copy/paste from a tutorial and apparently it worked for many others so I don't understand why it doesn't work for me! The table have been created so that is not an issue at all... The system will not enter anything into the mysql database and I don't get any errors either!!!!

The tutorial can be found here: http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-46916.html

I know it is not a secure system but I will sort that out as long as I can get it to work!!

Here is the codes:

**config.php**

```
<?php

$dbhost="localhost";
$dbusername="myusernam";
$dbpassword="mypass";
$dbname="dataname";

$connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) or die ("Could not select database");

?>
```

**add_news.php**

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if($submit)
{//begin of if($submit).

// Set global variables to easier names
$title = $_POST['title'];
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];


//check if (title) field is empty then print error message.
if(!$title){ //this means If the title is really empty.
echo "Error: News title is a required field. Please fill it.";
exit(); //exit the script and don't do anything else.
}// end of if
//run the query which adds the data gathered from the form into the database
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, dtime, text1, text2)
VALUES ('$title',NOW(),'$text1','$text2')",$connect);
//print success message.
echo "<b>Thank you! News added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";
}//end of if($submit).


// If the form has not been submitted, display it!
else
{//begin of else

?>
<br>
<h3>::Add News</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>">
Title: <input name="title" size="40" maxlength="255">
<br>
Text1: <textarea name="text1" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
Text2: <textarea name="text2" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add News">
</form>
<?
}//end of else

?>
```

**news_view.php**

```
<?php

// load the configuration file.

include("config.php");
//load all news from the database and then OREDER them by newsid
//you will notice that newlly added news will appeare first.
//also you can OREDER by (dtime) instaed of (news id)
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY newsid DESC",$connect);

//lets make a loop and get all news from the database
while($myrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{//begin of loop

//now print the results:
echo "<b>Title: ";
echo $myrow['title'];
echo "</b><br>On: <i>";
echo $myrow['dtime'];
echo "</i><hr align=left width=160>";
echo $myrow['text1'];

// Now print the options to (Read,Edit & Delete the news)
echo "<br><a href=\"read_more.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Read More...</a>
|| <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Edit</a>
|| <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid=$myrow[newsid]\">Delete</a><br><hr>";

}//end of loop

?>
```

Comment: what is `$submit` in `add_news.php` ... u have to define `$submit=$_POST['submit'];`

Comment: in Add_news.php you have `<?` instead of `<?php`

Comment: Try to check if error reporting is set to 'true' on the host. You can write in the beginning of the script: error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Have you definitely set up the database with the same details as you use to connect? With the same structure etc..

Comment: if this is a copy+paste from a tutorial, then you need to find a better tutorial -- this is using obsolete PHP functions and poor coding technique, and is extremely vulnerable to being hacked.

Comment: oh, no surprise -- the tutorial dates back to 2004. Yikes. Find something newer than that. Please don't use code from that far back; PHP has changed a lot since then.

Comment: yes, i understand. any tutorial you can refer me to for creating a simple news system?

Comment: @roozfar - it's been a long time since I needed a tutorial like that, so I don't know of one off the top of my head. But a quick web search brought me to [this one](http://www.elated.com/articles/cms-in-an-afternoon-php-mysql/) which looks fairly good (it looks like it's using modern coding techniques, which is a good start, though I haven't got time to examine it in depth)

Answer (score 0):

This should be more of a comment, but because formatting options are very limited there and I have a lot to comment, here goes:

whoever wrote that example... did not the best job.

there is no error handling at all (the `mysql_query("INSERT...` ).

Please replace/expand:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, dtime, text1, text2)
VALUES ('$title',NOW(),'$text1','$text2')",$connect);
//print success message.
echo "<b>Thank you! News added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";
```

with

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO news (title, dtime, text1, text2)
VALUES ('$title',NOW(),'$text1','$text2')",$connect);
if ( $result ){
//print success message.
echo "<b>Thank you! News added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";
} else {
echo("Error: ".mysql_error() );
}
}//end of if($submit).
```

I believe the inserts are not running (for whatsoever reason, you now hopefully can see)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I did try your suggestion and i get this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in /add_news.php on line 31 and on line 31 is this: else
{//begin of else   any suggestions?

Comment: that is most likely because you munched one `}`  you will need one for the additional if/else I added (to get a error after insert if it failed) and the closing brace already been there `}//end of if($submit).` . I edited it into my answer

Comment: Thanks again. I did try that and I still get NO error but the system doesn't work either! :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes :

config.php

```
<?php


$username = "myusernam";
$password = "mypass";

try {
    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dataname', $username, $password);
    $connect->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

addnews.php

```
<?php

include("config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$title = $_POST['title'];
$text1 = $_POST['text1'];
$text2 = $_POST['text2'];


if(empty($title)){ 
echo "Error: News title is a required field. Please fill it.";
exit(); 
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO news (title, dtime, text1, text2) VALUES (:title, NOW(), :text1, :text2)";
         $stmt = $connect->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindParam(':text1', $text1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->bindParam(':text2', $text2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
         $stmt->execute();


echo "<b>Thank you! News added Successfully!<br>You'll be redirected to Home Page after (4) Seconds";
echo "<meta http-equiv=Refresh content=4;url=index.php>";


}
?>

<br>
<h3>::Add News</h3>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF ?>">
Title: <input name="title" size="40" maxlength="255">
<br>
Text1: <textarea name="text1" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
Text2: <textarea name="text2" rows="7" cols="30"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add News">
</form>
```

news_view.php

```
<?php



include("config.php");


$stmt = $connect->prepare('SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY newsid desc');
$stmt->execute();


while($sa = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {



echo "<b>Title: ";
echo $sa['title'];
echo "</b><br>On: <i>";
echo $sa['dtime'];
echo "</i><hr align=left width=160>";
echo $sa['text1'];


echo "<br><a href=\"read_more.php?newsid=$sa[newsid]\">Read More...</a>
|| <a href=\"edit_news.php?newsid=$sa[newsid]\">Edit</a>
|| <a href=\"delete_news.php?newsid=$sa[newsid]\">Delete</a><br><hr>";

}

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That didn't work either!! I don't understand what is going on!!!